# RegEx ошибка при компиляции Illegal repetition

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Вижу вот это при компиляции:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{ 
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at zad2.Finder.regex(Finder.java:75)
at zad2.Finder.getIfCount(Finder.java:35)
at zad2.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Есть 2 класса, вот код:

**Main.java**

```
package zad2;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception  {
    String fname  = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test.java";
    Finder finder = new Finder(fname);
    int nif = finder.getIfCount();
    int nwar = finder.getStringCount("variant");
    System.out.println("Number of the if statements: " + nif);
    System.out.println("Number of variant strings: " + nwar);
  }

}
```

**Finder.java**

```
package zad2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Finder {

    String p;
    public Finder(String fname) {
    p = fname;
}

public int getIfCount() {
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(Paths.get(p), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return 0;
    }

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String l = scan.nextLine();
        if (regex(l, "\\s[/]{2}\\s"))
            continue;

        counter += checkCounter(l, "\\s*if\\s*\\(.*\\)\\{?.*");
    }
    scan.close();
    return counter;
}

public int getStringCount(String string) {
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner scan;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(Paths.get(p), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return 0;
    }

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String l = scan.nextLine();
        counter += checkCounter(l, string);

    }
    scan.close();
    return counter;

}

public int checkCounter(String re, String s) {
    int counter = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

public boolean regex(String re, String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

}

Суть задания в том, что нужно написать класс с функциями, которые ищут в файле все ифы и выводит их кол-во ну и стринги считать, но там вроде нет ошибок. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, регулярные выражения все еще не полностью понимаю, потому могу тупить.

Comment: В ошибке же английским по белому написано, что синтаксис регулярки неправильный. Зачем вы такую портянку кода запостили то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в функции getIfCount() в строке

```
if (regex(l, "\\s[/]{2}\\s"))
```

перепутали местами параметры. На первом месте должно быть регулярное выражение, на втором - строка для поиска:

```
if (regex("\\s[/]{2}\\s", l))
```

В строке

```
counter += checkCounter(l, "\\s*if\\s*\\(.*\\)\\{?.*");
```

та же ошибка.